# How to install GWT SDK 1.5 from zip?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have Eclipse Indigo 3.7; I tried to install GWT SDK 1.5 to it but maybe I am doing something wrong here; Moreover, I've never installed gwt sdk from zip :(

The thing is the SDK is in zip file; I've tried to install it manually but I couldn't find any tips how to install older GWT SDK to new eclipse :(

So my question is how to install GWT SDK 1.5 to eclipse indigo 3.7?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the SDK+ Eclipse plugin from http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html

The plugin can be placed in Eclipse_HOME\plugins and restarting will eclipse will put in place the plugin needed.

Comment: I mean this SDK http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-windows-1.5.3.zip ; should I place it in plugin folder?

Comment: Using that directly won't work. You might need mainefest file in addition to zip file you have downloaded. So basically are you trying to make GWT 1.5 work with helios? Then I would suggest go ahead and install latest version of GWT from http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.6.html and then go to plugins directory, look for GWT plugin directory, and there replace the GWT with your extracted zip file, also make changes to mainfest file if needed. Not sure this will work, but worth a shot

Comment: If it is so unsafe is there a way to download SDK 1.5 with a site link? And what eclipse is supporting this SDK version?

Answer (score 6):

Extract the ZIP file to a folder.

Open **Window** >> **Preferences** >> **Google** >> **Web Toolkit** then click the **Add** button.

Locate the folder. Click OK.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have Google in preferences

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer about adding a new SDK through preferences:

If you want your new SDK to be in the same location as your old SDK, you can go into the eclipse plugins folder (should be at the same directory level as the Eclipse app), duplicate the old SDK folder (should be something like "/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0"), then rename it, drop in your new sdk folder and delete the old one. Now it looks like you installed it using the plugin.

Also, when you add the SDK using the preferences route as explained above, be sure to check the box next to the new one if you want to use that one as a default in the future.

Hope this helps someone.